# JSF works on Wildlfy to slow

Tags: performance, jsf, primefaces, jboss, wildfly

After migrating our jsf application from Jboss AS 7.1 to Wildfly-8.0.0.Final speed of request processing was decreased in about 100 times. I tried serf Internet, but I couldn't find any reason. If someone has any suggestions or ideas?

Dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.26.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Not sure, it's the issue with wildfly. Cuase I am using wildfly for sometime with no issues.

Comment: Are you using mojarra 2.1 or the bounded 2.2 one?

Comment: I'm using mogara 2.2.5

Comment: Tryed rollback to mojarra 2.1.
Performance has improved, but still isn't so good.
2.5s on WF again 200ms on EAP.
I've noticed that performance reduced only for large page.

Answer (score 0):

Try yo updare yo Mojarra 2.2.6  . There was a performance regression bug in 2.2.5 that affects to large pages

Comment: Same problema. Worked? Did you try It?